# Memory leak detection using instruments

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I am trying to figure out where is memory leaked in this piece of code ?

```
- (NSMutableArray *) fetchAidDetails:(NSNumber *) rowID {
    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
    FMDatabase *db = [[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self dbPath]] retain];
    if(![db open]) {
        [db release];        
        return [list autorelease];
    }

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select legislative_type, legislative_name from legislative_aid where official_id = %d", rowID.unsignedIntValue];

    FMResultSet *result = [[db executeQueryWithFormat:query] retain];

    while ([result next]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];        
        NSString *type = [[NSString alloc] init];
        type = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_type"];
        [item setObject:type forKey:@"legislative_type"];
        [type release];

        NSString *party = [[NSString alloc] init];
        party = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_name"];
        [item setObject:party forKey:@"legislative_name"];
        [party release];

        [list addObject:item];
        [item release];
    }

    [result release];
    [db close];
    [db release];

    return [list autorelease];
}
```

[item retainCount] gives 2 before [item release] and [list autorelease] will make the reference count 0, am i going something wrong here ?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: retainCount is useless;  don't call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Dont rely on `retainCount`. The system or the internal code of the classes can retain your object internally and release it later, that's their business and you can't know, so you don't really know what value to expect in `retainCount`. That's not the good way to search for leaks
- At multiple times in your code, you allocate an object (in your case an `NSString`), then ignore it to override the variable with some other value:

  ```
  NSString *party = [[NSString alloc] init]; // You allocate memory for an NSString object
  party = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_name"]; // then you completely forget about it and override your party variable with a different object
  ```

Thats quite like if you were doing:

```
int i = 5;
i = 12;
```

Of course the first value is useless and not needed. But in the case of your code, this value that you never uses allocate memory that is never reclaimed so it leaks.

- Then after your affected another object to your `party` variable, you later send a `release` to this new object. But `party` contains an autoreleased object already, as you affected `[result stringForColumn:xxx]` to it, and according to code naming conventions, this method returns an autoreleased object. So you do not need to send a `release` on this new object.

So your loop should simply look like the following instead:

```
while ([result next])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];        
    NSString *type = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_type"];
    [item setObject:type forKey:@"legislative_type"];

    NSString *party = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_name"];
    [item setObject:party forKey:@"legislative_name"];

    [list addObject:item];
    [item release];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ali for the response, I have already done it like that and getting the same error, here is a screen shot of instruments leaks http://imageshack.us/a/img198/4127/instrumentsleaks.png

Comment: I see allocations but no leak in your instruments capture

Comment: Sorry Ali if i was not clear, hear are the screen shots of call tree and method definition. call tree - http://imageshack.us/a/img210/1448/calltree.png and       http://imageshack.us/a/img713/4469/sourcexz.png

Comment: Maybe Instruments is capturing the memory too early try to embed the inner content of your `while` loop in an '@autoreleasepool { … }` statement to purge autoreleased object as soon as possible instead of waiting FoodReporter the end of the runloop. Did you try the static analyzer tool? (menu "Product" > "Analyze")

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *type = [[NSString alloc] init];
type = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_type"];
```

You are creating an NSString 'type' which has a retain count of one, but then assign a different object to it. Remove the first line and just use this:

```
NSString *type = [result stringForColumn:@"legislative_type"];
```

You also need to remove the `[type release]` since `stringForColumn` returns an autoreleased NSString (at least if it adheres to the Cocoa naming conventions).

Comment: - (NSString*)stringForColumn:(NSString*)columnName {
        return [self stringForColumnIndex:[self columnIndexForName:columnName]];
    } are they not the same ?

Comment: Did you fix both `type` and `party`? You can use the complete code as given by AliSoftware. I don't understand what you mean by "the same".